# Is LEA [x], [y] permitted?

Tags: assembly, x86

Are you permitted to do an abstract call with LEA like:

```
LEA [x], [y]
```

where x and y are a valid registers or addresses.
Someone asked me the other day and I had no idea.
Load Effective Address will load y into the address x's 
contained value is pointing to, I think.
If this manner of code is valid what would one do with this?

Comment: What do you think with: `abstract call`? LEA isn't a `call` instruction!

Comment: No; assembly is rigid like this. The ability to use an arbitrarily complex expression anywhere instead of a constant or a variable is one of the reasons high level languages were invented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The only valid form of LEA is `LEA register, memory`.  (i.e. the destination operand must be a register).  Consult Volume 2 of the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual for an exhaustive reference on the matter.

The sequence:

```
LEA reg, [y]
MOV [x], reg
```

is equivalent to your hypothetical instruction; this isn’t a terribly useful sequence, but it isn’t useless either.  Among other purposes, it can be used to store a pointer that directly references a struct or array member.